# Specifying that certain computers / servers do not copy over a roaming profile when logging in?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, rdp, roaming-profile

We have a Windows Server 2008 r2 Standard and a server that everybody logs into using RDP which runs Windows Server 2003.  Now when people log into the RDP server, they only use an MS-Access frontend as their shell, explorer doesn't even run.  However...it appears that all of their roaming profiles are needlessly being copied over to the RDP server when they log in.

Is there some way to tell Windows Server 2008 r2 to NOT copy their roaming profile when they login to the RDP server?  But still allow their roaming profiles to be loaded everywhere else?

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner and simple to just set separate profiles for the Terminal Server logins in the user accounts?

Comment: Sounds like an idea...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a GPO for the server where you don't want roaming profiles loaded and enable the "Only allow local user profiles " group policy setting. Then either create an OU for this server and move the computer account to this OU and link the GPO to this OU or link the GPO to the domain and use security filtering to apply it to the specific server.

Comment: The system admin (not me) tried this today and unfortunately it didn't work.  We tried deleting a user directory in C:\Documents and Settings\ and when the user logs back in, the directory is still repopulated with their Roaming Profile.  Is there anything else that can be tried?

Comment: Are you sure that you've got the GPO linked to the right OU and server? Since this is a Computer Configuration setting did you reboot the server after applying the GPO?